# Bad sectors and SMART failure on hard drive

Tags: linux, hard-disk, disk, smart

I have a 500Gb hard drive with 20 bad sectors according to `gnome-disk`, and when I try to run a SMART self-test, it fails at `reading`. But `gnome-disk` shows that every other SMART attribute is `OK`, and this SMART failure doesn't kick in my motherboard's UEFI SMART failure warning on boot.

Is the hard drive unreliable? Can I still use it safely? Is there anything I can do to fix it or prevent failure?

Comment: Please edit question with output of `smartctl /dev/sda -A` as root, so we can actually see the SMART attributes (instead of having to guess) and explain to you what they mean. But if you already have 20 bad sectors, and the SMART self-test encountered a 21st bad sector, it's definitely time to make a backup, and the drive is very likely on its way out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should replace your hard drive if you value your data.

SMART in consumer hardware grade is usually not very useful and the firmware mostly reports everything is OK; usually in business/server grade hardware it is more informative.

Bad sectors also usually are masked internally by the hard drive up to a point. By the time they start showing up/being visible to the outside, it is time to dump the media/hard drive and replace it with a new one.

See [Google Says Diagnostics Don't Catch Many PC Drive Failures](http://www.pcworld.com/article/129238/article.html)